# How to write a predicate listtran(L, R)?

Tags: prolog

How to write a predicate listtran(L, R),
L is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
R is [zero, one, ..., ten]

Example:

```
?- listtran([0,4,5], L).  
L = [zero, four, five].  
?- listtran(L, [two, ten, two]).  
L = [2, 10, 2].
```

Answer (score 2):

if you only have to go from 0-10, I would definitely start building a predicate that translates numbers to text names:

```
num(0,zero).
num(1,one).
num(2,two).
num(3,three).
num(4,four).
num(5,five).
num(6,six).
num(7,seven).
num(8,eight).
num(9,nine).
num(10,ten).
```

then using them in the listtran predicate is easy:

```
listtran(IntLst,TxtLst) :-
    maplist(num,IntLst,TxtLst).
```

to build this in a clearer way without the helper maplist predicate, try this:

```
listtran([],[]). %base rule
listtran([Int|IntRest], [Txt|TxtRest]) :-
    num(Int,Txt),
    listtran(IntRest,TxtRest).
```

Answer (score 1):

Form a pairing domain, `PairDom = [0-zero, 1-one, 2-two, ...]` and use `member( X1-Y1, PairDom)`:

```
pair(A,B,A-B).

listtran(L,R):-
    maplist(pair,[0,1,2,3, ...,10],[zero,one, ...,ten],PairDom),
    maplist(pair,L,R, ...),
    maplist(member, ...).
```

To get a feel for how this might work, try it:

```
?- PairDom=[0-zero, 1-one, 2-two], member(1-Y1,PairDom).
Y1 = one

?- PairDom=[0-zero, 1-one, 2-two], member(X1-three,PairDom).
No.
```